# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar un elemento div o html después de enviar un formulario y recuperar información de una vista en Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Actualmente, cuando el usuario introduce una cadena en un campo de entrada y hace clic en el botón enviar, esto invoca una vista que devuelve a través de return render(request, 'index.html', context)un contexto que básicamente contiene datos que se muestran en una tabla.

Me gustaría que dicha tabla sea visible solo después de enviar el formulario y no antes y que cuando esté visible muestre la información obtenida de la vista.

El problema es que si a través del estilo en línea hago que esta tabla no sea visible, por ejemplo de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="row" id="searchVariantTable" style="display: none;">
    <!-- ALGUNA TABLA AQUI -->
</div>
```

Y luego uso el evento onsubmit para formulario o onclick para botón, no funciona. (Funciona parcialmente, puedo ver el tbody pero falta thead, así que básicamente no puedo mostrar los datos recuperados de la base de datos).

Del mismo modo, si intento algo como esto:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#searchVariantTable').hide();
  $('form').submit(function(e) {
      $('#searchVariantTable').show();
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Tampoco funciona.

Creo que la última opción, si no me equivoco, es AJAX, pero no estoy muy seguro de cómo hacer algo así con Django (es la primera vez que uso Django)

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Hay alguna opción que me falte?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar usando if else en la plantilla de django:

```
index.html
<form method="post">
<input type="submit">
</form>
{% if allowed == "yes" %}
<!-- your table code -->
{% endif %}


and in views.py
if request.method == "POST":
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'allowed':'yes'})

else:
    return render(request,'index.html',{'allowed':'no'})
```